# Webhooks Python Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, webhooks

I want to try just basic webhooks with Python, but I'm getting this error:
(both devices are on the same WiFi of course)

```
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

**Sender code on MacBook -**

```
import requests
import json

webhook_url = 'http://172.16.150.215:5000/webhook'
data = { 'name': 'Testing Webhooks'}
         
r = requests.post(webhook_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

**Receiver code on Raspberry Pi -**

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.json)
        return 'success', 200
    else:
        abort(400)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

[image: webhooks error]

When I'm trying both sender/receiver code just on raspberry, it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have not made the flask server visible through the local network.
it will only accept requests coming from localhost (so the raspberry pi).
you have to replace 'app.run' by 'app.run(host="0.0.0.0")', which will accept all requests from the local network. (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#public-server)

Finally, as a security measure, I strongly advise you to activate a firewall on your raspberry in order to allow only the connections to the ports you want (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04 )